# File download from google

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, salesforce, apex

I'm working on Google drive integration with salesforce. Currently I'm facing file corruption when I tried to download file using java script. My code is as followed

```
function downloadGDriveFile() {
    var id = '0B3EI0BFOUwSydHZNZXdIZ3lDZzg';
    var downloadUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+ id+'?alt=media';
    var accessToken = MY ACCESS TOKEN;
    var mType = 'image/jpeg';
    var name = 'Internet_of_Things.jpg';

    if (downloadUrl) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', downloadUrl);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      xhr.onload = function() {
        onDownload(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function() {
        //downloadFile(null);
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    else {
      alert("Unable to download file.");
    }
  }

  function onDownload(data) {
    var filename = 'Internet_of_Things.jpg';
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/jpeg" });

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                //window.location = downloadUrl;
            }
            alert(11);
            //URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 1); // cleanup
        }
}
```

when file is downloaded file is corrupted.File content shown as follow

���� JFIF    �� hExif  MM *           >       F(       1       N          Paint.NET v3.5.11 �� C �� C�� ��" ��

Dose any one can help me to sort this out. Do I need to encode or decode the Response from Google REST API?

Comment: In what way is that corrupt? It looks like a jpg file to me.

Comment: It is JPG but, it could open as a image